# Error handling in pageres (PhantomJS)

Tags: node.js, error-handling, phantomjs

I'm trying to work out how to handle errors in a simple [Pageres](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) script.

At the moment, when it runs, it runs just how I want it. But when there's an error, it hangs and the server requires a reboot.

All I want it to do:

1. If there's an error, write a message to a log file (in /var/log)
2. Exit

Any ideas? I've tried all sorts of things, and I don't think it's very hard but I'm not at all experienced with Node or PhantomJS.

```
const Pageres = require('pageres');

const pageres = new Pageres({
    delay: 2,
    filename: '<%= url %>-<%= size %><%= crop %>'
})

.src('https://example.com/', ['1920x1080'], {crop: false})
.dest('/home/storepictures/')
.run()
.then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pageres.on('warn', function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: did this work for anyone? I get an error stating pagers.on is not a function

Comment: @JackMarchetti You have mistype in `pagers`, it should be `pageres`

Comment: Hi, that was just a typo here. in my code it was correct.  Can you give an example of how this should look with the other code as well - i'm new to node.

Comment: @JackMarchetti take a look to the [documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres#usage)

Comment: I did.  Adding your suggestion results in an error: TypeError: pageres.on is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
const Pageres = require('pageres');

const pageres = new Pageres({
    delay: 2,
    filename: '<%= url %>-<%= size %><%= crop %>'
})

.src('https://example.com/', ['1920x1080'], {crop: false})
.dest('/home/storepictures/')
.on('warning', handleWarnings)
.run()
.then(() => console.log('done'));

function handleWarnings(warnings){
    console.log('warnings ::: ', warnings);
}
```